# find_elements() returns False even the Element exist in the page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

so I have a list of queries and am trying to filter Queries that have Google Snippets.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "D:\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
with open('queries.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        query = line.replace('\n','').replace(' ','+')
        url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&gl=us&hl=en"
        driver.get(url)
        if(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "V3FYCf")):
            print(query)                             
driver.quit()
```

The problem is that sometimes the Query has Google Snippet (a class `"V3FYCf"` exists) but `driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "V3FYCf")` returns False.

I think it's because the page didn't load fully before `find_elements()` was executed. So I used `WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "V3FYCf"))`. But it didn't solve this problem.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you so much.

I want to print out Queries that have Google Snippets.

Comment: We can't help without seeing an example.  Can you provide an actual example page that fails?

Comment: Also, `class="V3FYCf"` feels very much like a temporary generated class name.  Are you sure this exact class name will always be used?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you for your reply. I was wrong. I saw some Queries have GG Snippets (class "V3FYCf" exists). However, when checking the output, I didn't see them printed out. So I thought that because find_elements() returns False.

Comment: I did more research and found out that it's because of some queries that Selenium didn't open a new page and search them on Google.
Ex: I have "query1, query2, query3". Selenium will search query1 on GG, then query 3, and it forgets query 2. I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#Open the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q=Isearchsomething&gl=us&hl=en"
driver.get(url)

querys = date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3")))

for query in querys:
    print(query.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Things to have into account:

- `presence_of_all_elements_located`: Will return a list of elements, so you can not print their texts, you can make a loop to print the content for example as I did
- Do not use locators as `By.CLASS_NAME, "V3FYCf")`, they seems to be autogenerated, better to use a more common locator